# Json webservice registration in android studio

Tags: android, json, web-services

> I used this code to create a registration form using json webservice but when am running the app it returns failure message.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Register extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
EditText editTextName,editTextemail,editTextmobile,  editTextUserName,editTextPassword;
TextView editTextsignin;
Button btnCreateAccount;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://beauty.limitscale.com/webservices/userregister";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    editTextName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    editTextemail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    editTextmobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.mobile);
    editTextUserName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    editTextPassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    editTextsignin=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.login);
    btnCreateAccount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);
    // Attached listener for login GUI button


    editTextsignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentSignUP = new Intent(Register.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intentSignUP);
        }
    });

    btnCreateAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = editTextemail.getText().toString();
            if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
                editTextemail.setError("Invalid Email");
            }

            String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
            if (!isValidName(name)) {
                editTextName.setError("Invalid Name");
            }

            String mobile = editTextmobile.getText().toString();
            if (!isValidMobile(mobile)) {
                editTextmobile.setError("Invalid Mobile number");
            }

            String userName=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
            if (!isValidUsername(userName)) {
                editTextUserName.setError("Invalid UserName");
            }
            String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
            if (!isValidPassword(password)) {
                editTextPassword.setError("Invalid Password");
            }
                           if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||email.equals("")||name.equals("")||mobile.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }

            else
            {                    
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            new CreateUser().execute();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {        
    new CreateUser().execute();
}
private boolean isValidName(String name) {
    if (name != null && name.length() > 6) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private boolean isValidUsername(String userName) {
    if (userName != null && userName.length() > 6) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private boolean isValidPassword(String password) {
    if (password != null && password.length() > 6) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private boolean isValidMobile(String mobile) {
    if (mobile != null && mobile.length() == 10) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}

class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    boolean failure = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating User...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        String name = editTextName.getText().toString();
        String email = editTextemail.getText().toString();
        String mobile = editTextmobile.getText().toString();
        String username = editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        try {                
            java.util.List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("customername", name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("useremail", email));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("usernumber", mobile));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            Log.d("request!", "starting");

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);

            // full json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success element
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("User Created!", json.toString());
                finish();
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }else{
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);

            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }
    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null){
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}}
```

> I am new to webservice please help me , i dont know where i did the make

**JSONParser**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {
}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){               
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}}
```

**Log**

```
    02-14 15:58:59.174  15671-15671/com.example.limitscale.beautylog D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-14 15:58:59.254  15671-15671/com.example.limitscale.beautylog D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1076K, 10% free 69763K/76748K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
02-14 15:58:59.274  15671-15671/com.example.limitscale.beautylog I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 83.034MB for 11494128-byte allocation
02-14 15:58:59.564  15671-15737/com.example.limitscale.beautylog D/Login attempt﹕ {"data":null,"message":null,"status":"Failed"}
02-14 15:58:59.584  15671-15737/com.example.limitscale.beautylog W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for success
02-14 15:58:59.584  15671-15737/com.example.limitscale.beautylog W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
02-14 15:58:59.584  15671-15737/com.example.limitscale.beautylog W/System.err﹕ at org.json.JSONObject.getInt(JSONObject.java:444)
02-14 15:58:59.584  15671-15737/com.example.limitscale.beautylog W/System.err﹕ at com.example.limitscale.beautylog.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:193)
02-14 15:58:59.584  15671-15737/com.example.limitscale.beautylog W/System.err﹕ at com.example.limitscale.beautylog.Register$CreateUser.doInBackground(Register.java:147)
02-14 15:58:59.594  15671-15737/com.example.limitscale.beautylog W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
02-14 15:58:59.594  15671-15737/com.example.limitscale.beautylog W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-14 15:58:59.594  15671-15737/com.example.limitscale.beautylog W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
02-14 15:58:59.594  15671-15737/com.example.limitscale.beautylog W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
02-14 15:58:59.594  15671-15737/com.example.limitscale.beautylog W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
02-14 15:58:59.594  15671-15737/com.example.limitscale.beautylog W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-14 15:58:59.904  15671-15671/com.example.limitscale.beautylog I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41e9d048 time:5095895
```

> here is my logcat message

Comment: Please log `json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);` and tell me what was the result ? Or post your stacktrace which will help use identify your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a key which does not exist.

The response form server is this:

```
D/Login attempt﹕ {"data":null,"message":null,"status":"Failed"}
W/System.err﹕ org.json.JSONException: No value for success
```

You can check if it exist before using it, like this:

```
if (json.has("status")) {
    String status = json.getString("status"));
}
```

**UPDATE**:
You could change the following tag from this:

```
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
```

To this:

```
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "status";
```

Maybe change the name of the variable to, say, `TAG_STATUS`

Comment: So how can i change it , actually i checked it using postman but not updated

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hope I've understood your question correctly. If you'r asking how should you access the api endpoint (post, get, what parameters) then you would need to have access to the server side code or the documentation. @SivakumarS

Comment: Ya i got it man but by making this changes , but still my function is not working

Comment: You mean why are you getting this response from the server:  `{"data":null,"message":null,"status":"Failed"}`?